# How to Change Version of Existing Android Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, version, project

Existing android project in eclipse version is 4 4 2. Can I change it as 4 2 2 without new project?

Comment: Trying to reduce the app version? Why?

Comment: I think this project may be not work for 4 2 2 android mobile phones?

Comment: I guess you are talking about minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion, are you?

Comment: Yeah. In the beginning, I selected 4.4 as target SDK. Can work this project for 4 2 ?

Comment: If your minSdkVersion is lesser than of 4.2.2 than it should work.

Comment: How to see minSdkVersion?

Comment: Its in your project manifest.xml file

Comment: Oh thanks. It must be android:minSdkVersion="8".Let's say I change 8 as 11. Is it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in AndroidManifest.xml file, find

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

change the minSdkVersion to 17 for JellyBean